# ¿Cómo hacer clic sobre elementos de gráfica en highchart para automatizar?

Tags: java, selenium, highcharts, selenium-webdriver

Necesito automatizar el clic sobre las series que hacen parte de la leyenda del gráfico adjunto para activarlas/desactivarlas y también sobre los demás elementos de la gráfica, pero no he logrado encontrar el localizador de estos elementos y que luego pueda usar en el código.

Estas son las cosas que he intentado hasta el momento para encontrar un localizador válido:

- Utilizando el plug in Relative Xpath Helper. Cuando hago click derecho como indica el plug in para detectar el elemento de interés, se genera el mensaje: "No Unique Identifiers found".
- Utilizando Selenium IDE configurado con las librerías de Smartgwt para Selenium 'user-extensions.js' y 'user-extensions-ide.js'. Cuando utilizo esta herramienta, se genera el mensaje de error: "LOCATOR_DETECTION_FAILED".
- Utilizando el plug in Selenium Page Object Generator. Cuando se genera el archivo java correspondiente, no se genera ninguna referencia en relación a esta gráfica y sus elementos.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme.

¡Gracias y que tengan un buen día!

[image: Gráfica]

```html
<g class="highcharts-legend" zIndex="7" transform="translate(-32,110)">
  <g zIndex="1" clip-path="url(#highcharts-2)">
    <g transform="translate(0,1)">
      <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(8,3)">
        <path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke="#C00000" stroke-width="2"></path>
        <path fill="#C00000" d="M 8 9 C 10.664 9 10.664 13 8 13 C 5.336 13 5.336 9 8 9 Z"></path>
        <text x="21" y="15" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;color:#274b6d;fill:#274b6d;" text-anchor="start" zIndex="2">
          <tspan x="21">Worst Inventory On Site</tspan>
        </text>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(8,21)">
        <path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke="#3A5723" stroke-width="2"></path>
        <path fill="#3A5723" d="M 8 9 C 10.664 9 10.664 13 8 13 C 5.336 13 5.336 9 8 9 Z"></path>
        <text x="21" y="15" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;color:#274b6d;fill:#274b6d;" text-anchor="start" zIndex="2">
          <tspan x="21">Total Ins</tspan>
        </text>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(8,39)">
        <path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke="#CCC" stroke-width="2"></path>
        <path fill="#CCC" d="M 8 9 C 10.664 9 10.664 13 8 13 C 5.336 13 5.336 9 8 9 Z"></path>
        <text x="21" y="15" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;color:#CCC;fill:#CCC;" text-anchor="start" zIndex="2">
        <tspan x="21">Total Outs</tspan>
       </text>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(8,57)">
        <path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" stroke-dasharray="2,2" stroke="#CCC" stroke-width="2"></path>
        <path fill="#CCC" d="M 8 9 C 10.664 9 10.664 13 8 13 C 5.336 13 5.336 9 8 9 Z"></path>
        <text x="21" y="15" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;color:#CCC;fill:#CCC;" text-anchor="start" zIndex="2">
          <tspan x="21">Inventory On Site</tspan>
       </text>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(8,75)">
        <path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" stroke-dasharray="6,2" stroke="#CCC" stroke-width="2"></path>
        <path fill="#CCC" d="M 8 9 C 10.664 9 10.664 13 8 13 C 5.336 13 5.336 9 8 9 Z"></path>
        <text x="21" y="15" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;color:#CCC;fill:#CCC;" text-anchor="start" zIndex="2">
        <tspan x="21">Inventory On Transit</tspan>
       </text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
```

Comment: Hola Nathalia Bienvenido/a a [StackOverFlow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)  Mira [ask] y [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad. Además deberías realizar el [tour] para entender mejor como funciona el sitio. **Que has intentado hacer hasta el momento?**

Comment: añade tambien el codigo html relevante, para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: abrir el web con chrome/firefox , localizar el SVG del chart (inspeccionar elemento) y a partir de ahí podes ver los distintos groups y clases. el onClick por lo general está definido en cada `g` con clase "`highcharts-legend-item`" dentro de un grupo con clase `highcharts-legend`

Comment: botón derecho sobre el svg y "copy element/copiar elemento" ahí te va a dar el código de todo el svg, entre otras cosas el ID para localizarlo y de ahí encontrar el Xpath ó seleccionarlo por clase

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias a todos! Al final del comentario de @j.barrio comento cómo me ayudó a solucionarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma de obtener los objetos de dentro del SVG mediante Xpath es esta:

```
.//*[name()="g" and @class="highcharts-legend"]//*[name()="text"]//*[name()="tspan" and text()="Installation"]
```

Por lo que la forma de interactuar por ejemplo con este grafico de ejemplo de su [pagina](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic) es:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='g' and @class='highcharts-legend']//*[name()='text']//*[name()='tspan' and text()='Installation']").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

¡Muchas gracias @j.barrio! 
Tu respuesta me ayudó a resolverlo, pues utilicé una instancia ya creada del driver y me referí al elemento utilizando el localizador tipo xpath que sugieres, poniendo al final el nombre del elemento en la gráfica y funcionó. 
Esta fue la forma como quedó la línea:

`sharedData.appInstance.findElement(By.xpath("//[name()='g' and @class='highcharts-legend']//[name()='text']//*[name()='tspan' and text()='Worst Inventory on Site']")).click();`